# How to select sum of the values with same id from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

tableKit

```
id_kit | id_product | quantity
1      | 5          | 5 
1      | 4          | 2 
1      | 10         | 10
2      | 12         | 1 
2      | 20         | 2
```

tableProduct

```
id_product | pco_cost 
5          | 100
4          | 50  
10         | 20 
12         | 10 
20         | 5
```

The result that i want

```
id_kit | cost_kit 
1 | 800
```

the sum of the cost of each product multiplied by the quantity where id_kit = "x"

**Edit**:(Copied from comments):
I try this:

```
SELECT 
  pco_cost * (SELECT pkt_quantity FROM cm_product_kit where kt_id_product_catalog = 20928) as pkt_cost 
FROM cm_product_cost 
where pco_prd_id_product = 20928
```

But only get result of 1 field, i want that all items with same id, returns the sum of each product.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if "php" is an appropriate tag for this sql question

Comment: This is a straight forward join with aggregation. What have you tried, and where are you having trouble?

Comment: I try this, SELECT pco_cost * (SELECT pkt_quantity FROM cm_product_kit where pkt_id_product_catalog = 20928) as pkt_cost 
FROM cm_product_cost where pco_prd_id_product = 20928

But only get result of 1 field, i want that all items with same id, returns the sum of each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple join with aggregation (over multiplying). Lines #1 - 15 represent sample data; query you need begins at line #16.

```
SQL> with
  2  kit (id_kit, id_product, quantity) as
  3    (select 1, 5,   5 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 4,   2 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 10, 10 from dual union all
  6     select 2, 12,  1 from dual union all
  7     select 2, 20,  2 from dual
  8    ),
  9  product (id_product, pco_cost) as
 10    (select  5, 100  from dual union all
 11     select  4,  50  from dual union all
 12     select 10,  20  from dual union all
 13     select 12,  10  from dual union all
 14     select 20,   5  from dual
 15    )
 16  select k.id_kit, sum(k.quantity * p.pco_cost) cost_kit
 17  from kit k join product p on k.id_product = p.id_product
 18  group by k.id_kit
 19  order by k.id_kit;

    ID_KIT   COST_KIT
---------- ----------
         1        800
         2         20

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE     @tableKit TABLE (id_kit int, id_product int, quantity int)
INSERT INTO @tableKit VALUES
            (1,  5 ,  5)
        ,   (1,  4 ,  2)
        ,   (1, 10 , 10)
        ,   (2, 12 ,  1)
        ,   (2, 20 ,  2)

DECLARE     @tableProduct   TABLE   (id_product int, pco_cost int)
INSERT INTO @tableProduct   VALUES
            ( 5 , 100)
        ,   ( 4 ,  50)
        ,   (10 ,  20)
        ,   (12 ,  10)
        ,   (20 ,   5)

SELECT  
        id_kit
    ,   cost_kit    =   SUM(cost_kit)
FROM    (   
            SELECT
                        id_kit      =   TK.id_kit
                    ,   cost_kit    =   TP.pco_cost * TK.quantity
            FROM        @tableKit       TK
                JOIN    @tableProduct   TP  ON  TP.id_product   =   TK.id_product
        )   R
GROUP BY id_kit
```

Comment: OP has tagged the question with `Oracle` but the solution you are proposing is not a valid Oracle query. Though it is close to valid

Comment: Thanks bro, this is usefull, but te answer of Littlefoot works

Comment: I get the same results. Just in two steps. The inner select gets all rows, the outer gets the summary. Littlefoots solution works fine too, it is just one step. Pick the one works better for you.